Dart Unknown evaluation response type: null
I have recently started learning Dart, however I am having a very specific issue with the readLineSync command.
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int mxm;
  String a;
  print('Enter Maximum Marks:');
  a = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print(a);
  print('Enter Obtained Marks:');
  mxm = int.parse(a);
  print(mxm);
  print(mxm + 500);
}

It always displays this message, no matter the input.

Unknown evaluation response type: null

No one I know personally has any idea how to solve this issue. I have taken the exact same steps to install Dart as they have, and they don't see any issue with it. I have tried reinstalling VS Code and Dart, and even creating a new file, but the result is always the same. Is there anything that I am missing? Is this an installation problem, or is there something wrong with the code?

Welcome to stackoverflow. Just wanted to let you know that it is much easier to answer your question if you post the code and  error message  instead of an image. For example, now,  I had to type your code first just to try to reproduce the error.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

I could not reproduce your error using dart 3.3.4 and vscode 1.88.1. What is your setting in: Preferences > Dart > Run and Debug > Dart: Cli Console?

@DanR I'll keep that in mind, thank you. I thought a picture would be more useful as the code is supposed to be functional.
The preference for Dart: Cli Console is debugConsole by default

The vscode default debug console does not accept user input. To debug a program requiring user input you will have to set: Preferences > Dart > Run and Debug > Dart: Cli Console to Terminal (or alternatively External Terminal).

Thank you for this. I tried changing to Terminal and External Terminal, and the program works fine. In addition, is it possible for the output to appear in the Output Window?
